# Apache sending POST request twice

Tags: apache-http-server, php, lamp

I have a e-commerce shop and I've been noticing that on random intervals that orders would be created twice, sometimes 3 times. I found something strange in Apache's access logs that seems to be the cause:

```
SAME.IP.ADDRESS - - [08/Apr/2019:07:55:09 +0200] "POST /da/index.php?option=foo&task=orders.ajaxCheckActionPermissions HTTP/1.1" 200 218 "http://www.example.org/da/ordrer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
SAME.IP.ADDRESS - - [08/Apr/2019:07:55:18 +0200] "POST /da/ordrer HTTP/1.1" 303 456 "http://www.example.org/da/ordrer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
SAME.IP.ADDRESS - - [08/Apr/2019:07:55:20 +0200] "GET /da/ordrer HTTP/1.1" 200 13158 "http://www.example.org/da/ordrer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
SAME.IP.ADDRESS - - [08/Apr/2019:07:55:22 +0200] "GET /da/index.php?option=foo&task=shop.ajaxGetShoppingCart&_=1554702922260 HTTP/1.1" 200 762 "http://www.example.org/da/ordrer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
SAME.IP.ADDRESS - - [08/Apr/2019:07:55:18 +0200] "POST /da/ordrer HTTP/1.1" 303 456 "http://www.example.org/da/ordrer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
SAME.IP.ADDRESS - - [08/Apr/2019:07:55:23 +0200] "GET /da/ordrer HTTP/1.1" 200 13158 "http://www.example.org/da/ordrer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
SAME.IP.ADDRESS - - [08/Apr/2019:07:55:24 +0200] "GET /da/index.php?option=foo&task=shop.ajaxGetShoppingCart&_=1554702924422 HTTP/1.1" 200 761 "http://www.example.org/da/ordrer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

The second POST is the original form submission and the following 2 GETs are running as normal. However, the very next POST has the same timestamp as the previous POST.

I thought it could have been a form submit button being pressed twice, but I have JS preventing that, not to mention the entire checkout page is powered by JS, so a user wouldn't have been able to complete the checkout process, so it couldn't have been a double click.

Could it be a configuration problem with Apache? Or something entirely different? I'm not very advanced with Apache, but I'll provide info as requested.

I'm running a LAMP stack:

- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache is not **sending** the POST twice - it is **receiving** it twice. This is very likely a bug in the JS part of your application.

To diagnose it, set a global variable `orderSent` to `false` on page load, then **before** sending the `POST /da/ordrer` first check if it is still false and fail if not, then set it to true (again **before** sending the request). This helps you find the bug and allows you to create a more permanent solution.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but could not reproduce the problem. I've also tried testing at different levels in the stack trace for the form submission and could not find any calls being duplicated.
I also tried using different browsers to see if it was JS incompatibility at play. No luck.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. It was indeed a JS bug. I was able to track down the offending JS code only after using Firefox's useful event listener inspection tool.
I want to also point out that this happens in Edge/IE browsers.